# MySQL will connect via Heidi SQL but can't query via php script

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, port

as the title suggests I have a MySQL database setup on port 3333 instead of 3306 and I can connect externally fine on Heidi SQL with a user, I have granted all privileges to that user, but when trying to connect via a php script, I cannot get it to load at all. I have allowed it through internal windows firewall and external and like I say I can connect but not query it would seem.

I am using the same database for a game server with different users and even tried the same user with different database but same mysql server. It's just php connectivity.

I've changed the port under mysqld in my.ini and commented out bind-address. Really picking my skull now!

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: 1 - what error message are you getting? 2- are you using the same user in PHP as you are on Heidi?

Comment: I either receive no error message, or connection timed out. I am connected to the same database with the same user for a game server and it still won't. It's as if the database doesn't like php connections?!

Comment: I have fixed it. It was the call from the php.ini to the extension folder. You MUST specify the full root path to the php dll extensions. I just had "ext"